# hover on parent and highlight all childs

Tags: css, hover

I have the following html:

```
<span id="spanus">
    <a href="#">child1</a>
    <a href="#">child2</a>
    <a href="#">child3</a>
</span>
```

and css:

```
span{
    background: gray;
    border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px;
}

span:hover{
   background: yellow;
   border: 2px solid #fbfbfb; 
}

a{
   padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

span a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
```

**[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/BEndP/30/)**

**My question is how can I have hover over all 3 a childs once of span when I hover the span**

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
span a:hover
```

to

```
span:hover a
```

It will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set hovered span a, not hovered a in span:

```
span:hover a{
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHXPb/1/